# in single addition my SQLite app showing double result

Tags: android, android-sqlite

**Java**

I added data one time in database but it shows 2 time same data in database and it s main problem there id no problem in my code. I think there is problem in insertion of code or may be it caused by version used by me. I don't know where is problem it is my first project on SQLite and I am a beginner in SQlite

```
Context context;
private static final String DatabaseName = "MyNotes";
private static final int DatabaseVersion = 1;

private static final String TableName = "myNotes";
private static final String ColumnId = "id";
private static final String ColumnTitle = "title";
private static final String ColumnDescription = "description";

public Database(@Nullable Context context) {
    super(context, DatabaseName, null ,DatabaseVersion );
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    String query = "CREATE TABLE " + TableName + " (" + ColumnId + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY 
                   AUTOINCREMENT, " + ColumnTitle + " TEXT, " + ColumnDescription + " TEXT);";
    db.execSQL(query);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TableName);
    onCreate(db);
}

void addNotes(String title, String Description){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(ColumnTitle,title);
    contentValues.put(ColumnDescription,Description);

    db.insert(TableName,null,contentValues);
    
    if (db.insert(TableName,null,contentValues) == -1){
        Toast.makeText(context, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(context, " Data added Successfully " , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
}

Cursor readAllNotes(){
    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TableName;
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = null;

    if (database != null)
      {
        cursor=database.rawQuery(query,null);
    }
    return cursor;
}

public void deleteAllnotes() {
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "DELETE FROM " + TableName;
    database.execSQL(query);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please review your code in your `addNotes` method.

Seems like you have inserted data twice:

```
void addNotes(String title, String Description) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(ColumnTitle,title);
    contentValues.put(ColumnDescription,Description);

    //db.insert(TableName,null,contentValues);
    
    if (db.insert(TableName,null,contentValues) == -1) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(context, " Data added Successfully " , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: add notes same as you provided but still I replaced it with your code and it still not working. I am providing you link of my github repo          https://github.com/dharmik953/Notes/tree/1.0.0.0.0.1/app/src/main/java/com/dharmik953/notes

Comment: I commented out the first call to db.insert and kept the one in the if statement.

Answer (score 1):

Wipe out your app's data and then comment out this:

```
db.insert(TableName,null,contentValues);
```

Please don't use `onUpgrade` if your app release isn't an update..

Clean up your code.

Remove this line also:

```
db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TableName);
onCreate(db);
```

`addNotes` should just return a value, so you should actually remove the Toast there.

Move the Toast to where you actually called `addNotes`

You shouldn't actually save your notes in the SQLite database. That should be in a File. Then maybe you could save file location in the           database.